# Rust join only specific string in a vector

Tags: rust, vector

Hello i have something like this this vec:

```
["1", "1", "1", "M", "foo bar", "1", "1", "2", "M", "foo", "ba", "r", "1", "1", "3", "M", "barfoo", "1", "1", "4", "M", "bar ", "foo"]
```

i need a general way to turn join the strings that are not single int characters or single aplhabetic characters for example that vec would become

```
["1", "1", "1", "M", "foo bar", "1", "1", "2", "M", "foobar", "1", "1", "3", "M", "barfoo", "1", "1", "4", "M", "bar foo"]
```

i would like a general way and no one only for this vector, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can just check (i)th and (i + 1)th element's length and if length is > 1 then join them

Comment: HI thank you for the response, i tried that but i can't figure out a working way maybe if you have time you can show me an example. thath would be great! thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn is_single_char(s: &str) -> bool {
    s.chars().count() == 1 && s.chars().all(|c| c.is_digit(10) || c.is_alphabetic())
}

fn merge_strings(vec: Vec<&str>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut current = String::new();

    for s in &vec {
        if is_single_char(s) {
            current.push_str(s);
        } else {
            if !current.is_empty() {
                result.push(current.clone());
                current.clear();
            }
            current.push_str(s);
        }
    }

    if !current.is_empty() {
        result.push(current);
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    let original_vec = vec![
        "1", "1", "1", "M", "foo bar", "1", "1", "2", "foo", "ba", "r", "1", "1", "3", "barfoo", "1",
        "1", "4", "bar ", "foo",
    ];

    let result_vec = merge_strings(original_vec);
    println!("{:?}", result_vec);
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: thank you but that does not work, i get that ["111M","foo bar","112","foo","ba","r113","barfoo","114","bar ","foo"]

Comment: Ok I might not have been quite clear on your desired outcome. I've updated the code, try again please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

solved like this

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let xs = [
        "12", "1", "1", "M", "foo bar", "1", "1", "2", "M", "foo", "ba", "r", "1", "1", "3", "M",
        "barfoo", "1", "1", "4", "M", "bar ", "foo",
    ];

    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for (is_separate, group) in xs
        .iter()
        .copied()
        .group_by(|x| {
            let x = x.as_bytes();
            match x.len() {
                1 => x[0].is_ascii_alphanumeric(),
                2 => x[0].is_ascii_digit() && x[1].is_ascii_digit(),
                _ => false,
            }
        })
        .into_iter()
    {
        if is_separate {
            result.extend(group.map(str::to_string));
        } else {
            result.push(group.collect::<String>());
        }
    }
    
    println!("{result:?}");
}
```

in the group_by condition you can check anything you want.
in the output remains a single r but just add the condition of only uppercase if that is a problem